# Why an infinite loop forms in the piece of JavaScript code below?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, recursion

In the isValid function, when trying to write any line of code in the first for loop, an infinite loop is created. For example when I try console logging i, it just keeps on logging it and never stops.

I guess it has something to do with recursion but i am not able to find exactly why.

The problem is here in the //check same row section

```
// is Valid
function isValid(board, pos, num){
    //check same row
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
      
        // any line here creates problem
        //console.log(i);
      
        if(board[pos[0]][i] == num && i != pos[1]){
            return false;
        }
    }

    //check same column
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
        if(board[i][pos[1]] == num && i != pos[0])
            return false;
    }

    //check grid
    var box_x = Math.floor(pos[0]/3);
    var box_y = Math.floor(pos[1]/3);
    for(var i=box_x*3; i<(box_x*3)+3; i++){
        for(var j=box_y*3; j<(box_y*3)+3; j++){
            if(num == board[i][j]){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
var board = [
    [8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,2,6,0,0,5,0],
    [0,0,9,8,0,0,0,0,4],
    [7,0,3,0,0,0,0,2,0],
    [0,0,0,0,4,0,0,8,1],
    [5,0,0,0,0,7,0,3,0],
    [0,5,0,0,0,9,2,4,0],
    [0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0],
    [9,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
]


// find Empty Cells
function findEmpty(board){
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<9; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == 0){
                var pos = [i, j];
                return pos;
            }
        }
    } 
    var pos = [99,99];
    return pos;
}

//is Valid

function solve(board){
    var pos = findEmpty(board);
    if(pos[0] == 99)
        return true;
    for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
        if(isValid(board, pos, i)){
            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = i;
            //div_update(pos[0], pos[1], i, board);

            if(solve(board))
                return true;

            board[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 0; //resetting Value
            //div_update(pos[0], pos[1], i, board);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

solve(board);
console.log(board);
```

Comment: Why does `solve()` call `solve()`?

Comment: The algorithm uses recursion (backtracking)to solve the board, that's why solve calls solve to check if the board is solved or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a infinite loop, if you print a console_log at line 7, your script will try print a value 3,976.879 times in the console. For a browser or editor console will be generate a freeze or stopping show new values after a few thousand printed lines.
If you run this script with node in the OS terminal, it takes about 15 minutes, after that done succefully.

Comment: And the solution to the obvious (15 minutes for a 9x9 board is a little too much) problem?

Comment: So what is the problem exactly there, for each call it should console log 9 values? What am I missing?

Comment: @JaySinha What your code do, is replace "0" positions with a value between "1" and "9" that does not repeat in the same row, column or diagonal, right? Therefore the isValid function will be called milions of times until find a perfect combination of values. You really would like print a console.log every time that is Valid is called? IO operations are slow, so, when you remove console.log the script run in a few seconds.